# Error non-numeric argument to mathematical function in R

Tags: r

Trying to solve this problem
Please conduct a similar power analysis using the pwr() package for a 2-level HLM analysis, where the Level-1 unit of analysis is individual (i.e., nursing students), and the Level-2 unit of analysis is a clinical group (there will be approximately 7 to 10 students per clinical group). The outcome measure (performance, ranging from 0 to 19) is a continuous variable, and the independent variable is study group membership (1 = intervention group, 0 = comparison group).

Based on the output of the power analysis using the pwr() package in R, what is the minimum number of clinical groups and the minimum total sample size needed to achieve 80% statistical power, assuming the following:

1. Effect size f = 0.1
2. Effect size f = 0.2
3. Effect size f = 0.3

wrote this code, but it is generating an error: "Error in ceiling(result$g): non-numeric argument to a mathematical function." I am currently unable to determine the correct solution for this issue.

````
library(pwr)

# Define the parameters
n <- 9
icc <- 0.1
power <- 0.8

effect_sizes <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)

results <- lapply(effect_sizes, function(effect_size) {
  # Find the minimum g that achieves at least 80% power
  result <- pwr.anova.test(k = 4, f = effect_size, sig.level = 0.05, power = power)
  
  # Extract relevant values from the result
  g <- ceiling(result$g)
  f_lower <- result$f.lower
  f_upper <- result$f.upper
  
  # Calculate sample size and power
  calculate_power(effect_size, g, f_lower, f_upper)
})

calculate_power <- function(effect_size, g, f_lower, f_upper) {
  # Calculate sample size
  sample_size <- round(n * g) # Use round() instead of as.integer()
  
  # Print results
  cat(paste("Effect size:", effect_size, ", Minimum groups:", g, ", Minimum total sample size:", sample_size, "\n"))
  cat(paste("95% Confidence Interval for Effect Size: [", round(f_lower, 4), ", ", round(f_upper, 4), "]\n"))
}```
````

Comment: You could print result after anova test and see if there is proper g

Comment: here i found the minimal sample needed using anova test

Comment: With `n = 9` per group, you are unlikely to achieve 80% power for an `effect_size` of `0.1`.